# I am not able add a link to open my iphone app

Tags: ios, web-services

What I am trying to do is, Send user a link in email, and then when user taps on the link. My iOS app should open.

I am giving:

```
<a href = "myappNAME://profile">
```

The issue I have been facing that the email link is not even clickable. 
I also completed the ios side as well. followed this link
http://skookum.com/blog/open-an-ios-app-from-an-email

Comment: What have you set in your plist (url scheme) to allow that?

Comment: @Larme, the problem is the link is not getting even clickable. nothing is happening when I tap on that the link. Can you please help me with this. I am been stuck from  long time.

Comment: Could you show exactly what you've put in your plist for allowing that? (even if you replace your app name with "myappName" as long as it's the same as the example link test).

Comment: I have added URL identifier and URL types >  URL Schemes . to the app name. 

1. the problem is the link in the email is not working.. 
 <p><center><a href="xxxxx://param">Verify Account</a> </center></p>

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it open your project plist and add a url type(See screenshot).Fill in the required information identifier should be your bundle identifier and for url scheme just put a string say "hello".Build the app,than go to safari and type hello:// this should open the App.And for the link in email should have this scheme and it will open the App.
[image]

Comment: <p><center><a href="xxxxx://param">Verify Account</a> </center></p>

I can not add link, in the safari if I type xxxxx://param 
Then its opening properly.

Comment: Than it must be an html issue if you link is not clickable your ios side is good

Answer (score 0):

The reason was email filters, they disable the links like "myapp://" .

So what I have to do is, add a link to another page and from their I added a redirect, and then It worked.